# Sort buttons in my app similar to iOS Multitasking

Tags: iphone, ios, swipe

I want to add buttons dynamically to a special area in my app. Users can swipe left or right to navigate between buttons like in iOS multitasking.

[image]

I just want to create an area completely same as iOS multitasking. How can I do this? Which components will I use, and how can I search this in google?

Comment: I'd suggest rotating a UITableView 90 degrees to make it a horizontal tableview. Or you could use a UICollectionView (iOS6+).

Comment: Why you suggest UITableView, What advantages do UITableView have over UICollectionView?

Comment: UITableview works on all versions of iOS, whereas Collection View will only work on iOS 6+

Comment: UICollectionView is only iOS6 and above. There is a pretty good backport called PSTCollectionView. I'd suggest a tableview because it is 1 dimensional data. Rotating the tableview isn't difficult, just be sure to rotate all the cells the opposite 90 degrees so they appear vertically.

Comment: Subclassing a `UITableView` and making it page horizontally would be a pain. Why not just use a simple `UIPageControl`? And it should also be noted that trying to *exactly mimic* a trait of iOS (esp. part of the home screen - cite AppStore Review Guideline 10.4) is immediate grounds for rejection by the App Review Board.

Answer (score 2):

The multitasking area is a UIScrollView with pagingEnabled = YES.  You can use a collection view to populate the scroll view, or you can manually lay the content out yourself.  If there's going to be a lot of dynamic content then collection view is probably the way to go because it does the reusable-cell thing that table views do.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html